# ViewPager inside RecyclerView ViewHolder with ViewPager2 as parent not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I notice after updating to `ViewPager2` that holds some fragment, the items in `RecyclerView` that has `ViewPager` stops working and not scrolling. Is there any solution to this without making custom ViewPager that overriding `onTouchEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use a NestedScrollableHost: https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/NestedScrollableHost.kt

Java version

https://gist.github.com/KhaledAlharthi/e7e52cdf689295abb76b9437e1e02228